# MS Bot framework: Let user post multiple data

Tags: botframework

I´m trying to find a way to let a user retrieve, edit and post multiple data in a table. Like this:

- A user asks for some entity, for e.g. Person
- The MS bot returns a table with all the attributes for that Person (for ex: age, name, address etc)
- The user can edit the data directly in the table, press send and the data
  stored in the DB.

Is there any support for this? Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Adaptive Cards** to provide the user with a 'Form' to fill out.  Not all channels support Adaptive Cards, but the list of supported channels is growing.  For more information, please see: https://adaptivecards.io/ and [howto: send-an-adaptive-card](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-add-media-attachments?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#send-an-adaptive-card)

Here is an example from **MS Teams**:

[image]

The card can be created using the Adaptive Cards library, or loaded from .json file like this:

```
string cardPath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "testcard.json");
string cardText = File.ReadAllText(cardPath);
var card = AdaptiveCards.AdaptiveCard.FromJson(cardText);

var reply = turnContext.Activity.CreateReply("card");
reply.Attachments.Add(new Attachment()
{
    Content = card.Card,
    ContentType = AdaptiveCards.AdaptiveCard.ContentType
});
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply);
```

Note: when the user submits the card, the activity.Value will contain a .json string of values:
[image]

Example Card .json:

{
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "version": "1.0",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "Tell us about yourself...",
      "weight": "bolder",
      "size": "large"
    },
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "We just need a few more details to get you booked for the trip of a lifetime!",
      "isSubtle": true,
      "wrap": true
    },
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "Don't worry, we'll never share or sell your information.",
      "isSubtle": true,
      "wrap": true,
      "size": "small"
    },
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "Your name",
      "wrap": true
    },
    {
      "type": "Input.Text",
      "id": "firstlast",
      "placeholder": "Last, First",
      "style": "text",
      "separataion": "none"
    },
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "Your email",
      "wrap": true
    },
    {
      "type": "Input.Text",
      "id": "email",
      "placeholder": "youremail@example.com",
      "style": "email",
      "separataion": "none"
    },
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "Phone Number"
    },
    {
      "type": "Input.Text",
      "id": "phone",
      "placeholder": "xxx.xxx.xxxx",
      "style": "tel"
    }
  ],
  "actions": [
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "Send",
      "data": { "personalInfo": "" }
    }
  ]
}

Comment: OK that is a good way for the user to input data. However, I want the opposite way - I want to present data in a table to the user.

Comment: One of your requirements is: "The user can edit the data directly in the table, press send and the data stored in the DB"  You could change the fields in this example, and rearrange them in a table where they have the values pre-populated with existing data.